# Rails installing mysql error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I want to install mysql2 gem but it keeps failing.

```
C:\Users\HuiHui\Documents\ruby 2.0.0>gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'
Fetching: mysql2-0.3.11.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
        --with-libmysqllib
        --without-libmysqllib


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2
.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-
0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

it keeps having the same problem despite changing versions, uninstalling and installing without any version and all. Can someone shed some light on this? I am doing things on a Windows..

Attached is the logs file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7rg6eibhhvlf21r/mkmf.log

**EDIT**

After trying the tutorial from medium, I've got this error.

```
C:\Users\HuiHui\sutdweb>gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=c:\mysql-connecto
r-c-6.1.5-win32
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-dir=c:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.5-wi
n32'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-mysql-dir=c:\my
sql-connector-c-6.1.5-win32
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Using --with-mysql-dir=c:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.5-win32
-----
checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
        --with-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-libmysqllib
        --without-libmysqllib


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2
.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-
0.3.16/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: did you check the log for more details like it says?

Comment: Silly question but: you are installing the mysql gem (which talks to the real mysql library). Have you actually installed mysql itself yet?

Comment: @sevenseacat yes ive checked but i do not understand what is in the logs...

Comment: @TarynEast yes! i have a mysql workbench too

Comment: Worth checking. The main reason I ask is that it says it's missing libmysql - it's possible that you still need to install some of the dev-headers for mysql.

Comment: @TarynEast ahhh. i m a newbie at this.. how do u install some dev-headers for mysql?

Comment: That depends on your OS - and I'm guessing windows here (I can only help you on ubuntu). I'd google for something like "installing mysql dev headers on windows" or the like.

Comment: I've had this issue in the past. I had to end up specifying the configuration options manually. I think my mysql junk was either named differently or in a different place than what was expected. Can't remember the details, it was years ago.

Comment: @pixelearth oh god how do u specify configuration options manually?

Answer (score 0):

In your response to how to specify configuration options with gem and mysql2, it's something like this:

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=c:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.1-win32
```

See details here:

https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone shed some light on this?

Sure - the problem is to do with Windows' compatibility with the `MYSQL2` gem - by default, Windows does not come with the MYSQL header files which are required to allow the gem to connect with MYSQL

In order to install it, you need to install the MYSQL C-Connector package, and use it to give your gem the C++ header files it needs to run:

--

We've written a tutorial about this [here](https://medium.com/p/a028f44d87f3)

It's actually relatively simple to install the `mysql2` gem if you do this :

> 1. Install / unzip the [MYSQL C-Connector **32 bit** package](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) on your system
> 2. Install the gem, referencing the path *without spaces*
> 3. Copy `libmysql.dll` to your Ruby installation

The first step is download the latest version of mysql 32-bit c-connector. Unzip / install into a path **without spaces** - this is essential.

The second step is to use the following command to install the gem, referencing the c-connector files:

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- ‘--with-mysql-dir=”C:\mysql-connector-path”’
```

Finally, you should copy the `libmysql.dll` file from the `/bin` folder of your `C-Connector` files to the `/bin` directory of `Ruby`

This should install the gem

Comment: Hi @Rich Peck i tried and they gave me this error... 

C:\Users\HuiHui\sutdweb>gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby--'--with-mysql-dir="C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-5.5.38-win32"'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: -ùplatform=ruby----with-mysql-dir="C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-5.5.38-win32öÆ

Comment: Sorry, that's a formatting problem with the command - let me fix for you

Comment: Should be okay now (if you copy the command from here, not medium)

Comment: gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby--'--with-mysql-dir="C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-5.5.38-win32"'

here! thank u!

Comment: I've added the error message from after trying out the steps... please take a look at it

Comment: Did you use the platform argument or not?

Comment: yes sir. tried and failed. i understand that it may be due to my putting the files in a directory with spaces as well so i've uninstalled the whole mysql package and reinstalled in c straight. but...still didnt work...